# Feed private key to pageant via STDIN

Tags: windows, powershell, pipe, stdin, pageant

Is there a way in Windows to trick or simulate the file, made from other command output?

What I am looking for is the following bash equivalent, but for Windows and pageant:

```bash
sops --decrypt "${f}" | ssh-add -
```

While Windows CLI has just this:

```
pageant.exe file1.ppk .... fileN.ppk
```

So, I do not have to output decrypted content to the file to securely [sdelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) after

Actually, if there is a better cli-fed alternative. CMD or Powershell based.
Keypass with agent plugin does not fit my workflow

Answer (score 1):

For strings/keys:

```
  PS> ConvertFrom-SecureString $f -key $key
```

For larger files you have a couple of options:

Windows Server:

```
  > cipher /d
```

.NET: Uses your CSP which may not be desirable

```
  PS> [System.IO.File]::Decrypt($f)
```

I can list many more options if need be but I don't know what you are trying to do.
Better to use higher-level solutions but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography can do what you want for sure.

Also clearly ssh-agent needs to be running for ssh-add.  Can use the ssh-agent (which is now built-in on Windows Server but also comes with Git) or OpenSSH's ssh-agent but neither service is started by default.

Comment: Thanks,
upvoted for " Can use the ssh-agent (which is now built-in on Windows Server but also comes with Git) or OpenSSH's ssh-agent" part

Answer (score 0):

```
sops --decrypt keyfile  |  ssh-add.exe -
```

works for me.

Now, is to mate the GIT_SSH and Putty with OpenSSH client, and the problem is solved